# Why is my svg "height" being overwritten by my footer's "bottom" positioning?

Tags: html, css, svg, scale

I have .svgs as objects within my .html

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/css-3.svg">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
```

I can scale all .svg in a separate .css

```
svg { height: 100px; }
```

I want my layout to have a fixed  and , and a scrollable

```
.header-container, .footer-container, .main-container { position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100%;}
.header-container, .footer-container {overflow: hidden;}
.main-container { top: 100px; bottom: 100px; overflow: auto;}
```

But when I include into the .css

```
.footer-container {bottom: 0;}​
```

The .svg files reset to their internal values (The .svg files are saved in a separate folder). Example:

```
<svg width="1773" height="2500" viewBox="0 0 256 361" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"><path d="M255.555 70.766l-23.241 260.36-104.47 28.962-104.182-28.922L.445 70.766h255.11z" fill="#E44D26"/><path d="M128 337.95l84.417-23.403 19.86-222.49H128V337.95z" fill="#F16529"/><path d="M82.82 155.932H128v-31.937H47.917l.764 8.568 7.85 88.01H128v-31.937H85.739l-2.919-32.704zM90.018 236.542h-32.06l4.474 50.146 65.421 18.16.147-.04V271.58l-.14.037-35.568-9.604-2.274-25.471z" fill="#EBEBEB"/><path d="M24.18 0h16.23v16.035h14.847V0h16.231v48.558h-16.23v-16.26H40.411v16.26h-16.23V0zM92.83 16.103H78.544V0h44.814v16.103h-14.295v32.455h-16.23V16.103h-.001zM130.47 0h16.923l10.41 17.062L168.203 0h16.93v48.558h-16.164V24.49l-11.166 17.265h-.28L146.35 24.49v24.068h-15.88V0zM193.21 0h16.235v32.508h22.824v16.05h-39.06V0z"/><path d="M127.89 220.573h39.327l-3.708 41.42-35.62 9.614v33.226l65.473-18.145.48-5.396 7.506-84.08.779-8.576H127.89v31.937zM127.89 155.854v.078h77.143l.64-7.178 1.456-16.191.763-8.568H127.89v31.86z" fill="#FFF"/></svg>
```

Why is the footer over-writing the values of the .svg in the .css? I will try to manage them inline, but was curious as to why it's happening.

Comment: How do your .svg files know about the .css file? I see no <link> tag in the file nor do I see a <?xml-stylesheet ?> instruction. You do know that CSS does not cross document boundaries and that your main page and your .svg files are all separate documents.

Comment: Well, before I added the footer, the external css was able to set the heights on all objects. When the footer is added this no longer works. I can add the link tag to each svg image, but I wanted to know why it worked before but not now.

Comment: Perhaps a bug somewhere. I don't see why what you're trying to do would work at all given you don't link the SVG file to the CSS file.

Comment: As I'm using the <object> tag and referencing the .svg in another folder, then applying styling to the <object> (not an svg), would that make a difference?

Comment: As long as you expect your CSS i.e. svg { height: 100px; } to do absolutely nothing at all. In which case, why did you write it?

Comment: And yet it clearly does do something, in both the case of <svg> and <object> - https://youtu.be/amNsTFFc40g. Strangely enough, I got it working as it did before simply by retyping ".footer-container {bottom: 0;}​" again...